# Greatest volumetric heat capacity

Tags: heat

Is there any substance with bigger volumetric heat capacity than water? According to [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities) water has the biggest known VHC. But I can't believe that in the 21. century we have no special material with larger VHC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a thesis that details construction and characterization of thin films with large volumetric heat capacities (some nearing $6\ MJ\cdot m^{-3}K^{-1}$):

[Volumetric heat capacity enhancement in ultrathin fluorocarbon polymers for capacitive thermal management](http://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/24118)